# GeoServer: Can I connect GeoServer with any geospatial database by adding data store?

Tags: geoserver, geotools

I want to connect geospatial database with GeoServer. GeoServer is not provided the out-of-box facility for the same. But I want to know the possibility to connect GeoServer with other geospatial databases by adding a new data store through GeoTools.

Need to add a New data store to connect with Vertica Database.

Comment: What is "GEO Spatial Database"? Please provide links to documentation. Or do you mean a generic name for products like PostGIS, Oracle Spatial, MSSQL Spatial etc?

Comment: basically, yes you can write a new datastore for any datasource that GeoTools doesn't currently support

Comment: Here is some basic information on "Spatial Database". Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_database

Comment: What spatial database product do you have in your mind? You used term "GEO spatial  database" which made me think that GEO is a name of a product yet unknown to me.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: please say exactly which database you wish to connect

Comment: @IanTurton I want to connect with Vertica Database. Currently, GeoServer has the functionality to connect with Postgresql / PostGIS. The same way I want to connect with Vertica database

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need to write a new `Datastore` for that database. Since it seems to [supply a JDBC connector](https://www.vertica.com/download/vertica/client-drivers/) it should be possible to copy and modify one of the existing [JDBC datastores](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/tree/main/modules/plugin/jdbc). You will need to then modify the  ["dialect" code](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/main/modules/plugin/jdbc/jdbc-postgis/src/main/java/org/geotools/data/postgis/PostGISDialect.java) and the [filter to sql code](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/main/modules/plugin/jdbc/jdbc-postgis/src/main/java/org/geotools/data/postgis/PostgisFilterToSQL.java) which encapsulate the individual database differences.